# Limit of product of two sequences.

Tags: limits

I am dealing with this limit problem. 
Let $$U_n=n^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})}\ \text{and}\ V_n=\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k^k\bigg)^\frac{1}{n^2},\ n>0.$$
Compute $$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}U_nV_n.$$
I did it using two different methods and I got different values. I tried to see where was my mistake but I couldn't.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \ln(U_nV_n)&=& ln U_n+\ln V_n\\
  &=& -\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\dfrac{1}{n})\ln n +\dfrac{\ln(1^1)+\ln (2^2)+\cdots +\ln(n^n)}{n^2}\\
  &=& -\dfrac{1}{2}\ln n-\dfrac{\ln n}{2n}+\dfrac{\ln 1}{n^2}+\dfrac{2\ln 2}{n^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n\ln n}{n^2}
  \end{eqnarray*}
From that, we get $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\ln (U_nV_n)=-\infty$, which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}U_nV_n=0$.

In the other hand, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \ln(U_nV_n)  &=& \ln U_n+\ln V_n\\
  &=& -\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\dfrac{1}{n})\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k\ln k}{n^2}\\
  &=& -\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k\ln k}{n^2}\\
  &=& -\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n^2}\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k\ln k}{n^2}\\
  &=& \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot \dfrac{-\ln n}{n^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k\ln k}{n^2}\\
  &=& \sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{n^2}(\ln k-\ln n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{n^2}\ln (\dfrac{k}{n})\\
  &=& \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{n}\ln (\dfrac{k}{n})\\
  \end{eqnarray*}
From that, we get that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\ln (U_nV_n)=\int_0^1x\ln xdx=-\dfrac{1}{4}$, which implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}U_nV_n=e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$.

Can anyone tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you show in more depth why you feel the first sequence has a limit of $-\infty$?

Comment: Be careful, when you take limit! $\lim \sum f_k \neq \sum \lim f_k = \sum f $ for $ f = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} f_k$;
I assume your terms: $\dfrac{\ln n}{2n}+\dfrac{\ln 1}{n^2}+\dfrac{2\ln 2}{n^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n\ln n}{n^2}$ all became $0$, while your first became $\infty$

Comment: Your evaluation of the limit in the first one appears to be wrong.